# jd edwards and ms dynamics integration with mule esb

Tags: mule

I am new to mule. I want to integrate mule with jd edwards and ms dynamics(installed in my system). How can I integrate these two?

```
                      1)jd edwards
                      2)Ms Dynamics..
```

Answer (score 2):

There are existing MS Dynamics Connector for Mule, as you can see here: http://www.mulesoft.org/connectors?title=microsoft+dynamics

I can not find a ready made JD Edwards connector but some people seem to have success in directly accessing it from flows: http://www.jdelist.com/ubb/showflat.php?Cat=0&Number=177192 Otherwise, you can use DevKit to create your own JD Edwards connector, around the JDE client for example, or by integrating their API.

So it seems possible to integrate both...

Comment: Thanks for you reply... but need more information how to use those connectors to integrate with ms dynamics which is installed in my system.

Comment: Did you follow the above link? There's even a video: http://www.mulesoft.org/connectors/microsoft-dynamics-crm-on-premise-connector

Comment: have followed. but my situation is different. I have installed ms dynamics in windows server 2008 and my desktop is client. how to integrate mule to ms dynamics?

Comment: Do you mean you're going to run Mule on your desktop?

Answer (score 2):

There is now a JDE connector that allows native and high performance connectivity from Mule. (For the initial client we worked with we found the web services approach wasn't able to meet the performance requirements and was limiting in terms of operations that could be called, hence we decided to build the connector.)

http://www.modusbox.com/products/jd-edwards-connector/.

The dynamics connector has also improved a lot in the past year: https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/#!/microsoft-dynamics-crm-integration-connector.

Answer (score 0):

And I'm the jdelist user who built the mule integration (when I was in the consultant field). So yes it's possible to call JDE BSSV or JDE BSFN (wrapping java connector or xml call object) from Mule flow. It's a one day job.